# power supply for multiple raspberry pi4

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-4

I am wondering if any one knows of a power supply that will power 4 or more raspberry pi4 with the type C plug? (Yes I would like the full 3 amps or more)

I thought of a standard ATX power supply, and get a bunch of USB-C cables and cut the other end off and solder them together.

The downside is its awful hacky, and then there is no safety mechanisms besides what the PSU provides.

Comment: I have been using this 12A step down and found it OK for Rpi3V+ https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32892386433.html

Comment: And I am using this charger for my Rpi4B: https://uae.digshop.com/products/xiaomi-power-delivery-60w-6-port-usb-c-desktop-charger/

Comment: @tlfong01  Link seems to be dead

Comment: Or try this: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004934433655.html